# Add input to table without styles

Tags: html, css

I'm adding inputs to my table td, but I want to show it in the same way that a simple cell. Here is my code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="Body">
    <tr>
      <td><input disabled style="with:100%;" value="data" /></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In simple words I want to show it like text, instead of showing borders and background. I tried adding `outline: none` but nothing happen.

Comment: `border: none; background: none;`

Comment: @4castle I really suck using CSS, that was a very easy answer omg! thanks

Comment: i think you meant to say `width: 100%`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3 things that you need to do to fix the style:

1. Remove the border using `border: none`
2. Remove the background using `background: none`
3. Add `color: initial` to remove the grey-ish color coming from disabled input

**Working code snippet:**

```css
input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Some Text</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="Body">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input disabled style="with:100%;" value="data" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```